# To what extent does LXC manage configuring the network interface in a container?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, dhcp, bridge, lxc

In the LXC config file we can specify an IP address for a container:

```
lxc.network.type=veth
lxc.network.link=br0
lxc.network.ipv4 = 10.1.0.35/16
lxc.network.flags=up
lxc.network.hwaddr= 00:16:3e:24:26:33
```

But if the container has the default configuration of DHCP, what's going to happen:

```
# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

- Does LXC act as a DHCP server for the container?
- Will the two configurations conflict with the container broadcasting requests for an IP before/after LXC attempts to manually configure the interface?
- Will LXC simply override whatever is in the containers configuration for eth0?

Comment: Why don't you try it? This is purely theoretical. However, one aspect I can shed light on: `dnsmasq` is running as DNS and DHCP server for the `lxcbr0` bridge by default. Otherwise global settings govern how the container configuration affects operation.